# Server 16.04 - Default Grub Boot Option Fails

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm able to get the server to boot by going into the advanced options and choosing the first option.

My question is how can I automate this? Requiring someone to be at the console during the boot process just to select the right option will not work long term.

I tried reading the grub manual and looking at the boot files but holy crap this is a nightmare! I just need to tweak this one setting... the old way was simple, just chose the default you want and bam your done.

Here's a copy of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: It should boot without any intervention. Hard to know what your problem is with what little you posted. Start with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup and post any errors you get and your config ;)

Comment: As you can see, all the boot parameters are gone from grub now. They appear to be some how auto generated by a script somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for someone not familiar with editing the `/etc/default/grub` file manually you can use a program called [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)

Under the General settings tab you will see default entry. Just select the entry you want it to default too. You can also set it to show/hide the menu and change the delay time. I still like to keep the menu and have a small wait time of like 3 seconds just in case I need to get to it easily during a boot.

If you want to set it by hand and edit the `/etc/default/grub` file you would need to change the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-21-generic"` or whatever  the correct line would be for the kernel you want .. notice the advance options line .. that is because the kernels are in a submenu.

once you have made and saved your changes you need to run `sudo update-grub` from a terminal for it to update the changes or it will just be overwritten next boot

Comment: Installed and ran the grub-customizer. Got this output:==== AUTHENTICATING FOR net.launchpad.danielrichter2007.pkexec.grub-customizer ===
Authentication is required to run Grub Customizer
Authenticating as: vision,,, (vision)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

Comment: sounds like it didn't launch as root for some reason ... try running it from a terminal with `sudo grub-customizer`